# How to define build-scoped settings in multi-project .sbt builds?

Tags: scala, sbt

As of sbt 0.13, the recommended way to define all configuration is [multi-project .sbt build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html). It is absolutely clear how to define settings for each project there; however, how one should define build-wide settings, for example, in `ThisBuild` or `Global` scopes?

With Scala build definitions it is clear: we have `settings` key coming from `Build` trait:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    someKey := someValue
  )
}
```

Now `someKey`'s value will be build-scoped by default. Alternatively, it can be defined directly in `.sbt` file with `ThisBuild` scope:

```
someKey in ThisBuild := someValue
```

However, there is no natural place to define these options in multi-project `.sbt` builds. I suspect that they should be defined in one of the projects with `ThisBuild` scope:

```
val someProject = project
  .settings(someKey in ThisBuild := someValue)
```

but this is very counterintuitive and not really clear: are such settings really applied globally or do they really belong to the specific project? What if I define the same key in multiple projects?

```
val project1 = project.settings(someKey in ThisBuild := someValue1)

val project2 = project.settings(someKey in ThisBuild := someValue2)
```

The documentation does not give any answers on this, unfortunately.

Note that I explicitly *do not* ask how to share global settings between builds or projects. I ask *specifically* about defining build-scoped settings.

Comment: Not really what you want, but you could define an implicit class with a method that adds the common settings to all the project, something like:`implicit class RichProject(project: Project) { def baseSettings(project: Project) = project.settings(...)} `

Comment: @EndeNeu, I'm not looking for sharing common settings between projects (I stated this explicitly). I'm looking for a way to assign a setting *in build scope*. These are very different things.

Comment: I think I don't get the question then, it seems to me that settings can either be applied on a project basis or to all the projects, doesn't _build-wide settings_ means for all the projects in the build?

Comment: @EndeNeu, do you know about scopes each setting may have? They are described in [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html). In short, each setting may be scoped by three axes, project, configuration and task. Project axis coordinate may point to a specific project or to entire build, and the latter is exactly what I mean. And no, build-scoped setting does not imply "applied to all projects", at least, not directly.

Comment: Just in case, I've also rephrased the title of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I've performed some experiments and found out the following. Here is an example `build.sbt`:

```
val testKey = settingKey[String]("A key for test")

testKey := "value in build.sbt"
testKey in ThisBuild := "build-scoped value in build.sbt"
testKey in Global := "global value in build.sbt"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    testKey := "value in root project",
    testKey in ThisBuild := "build-scoped value in root project",
    testKey in Global := "global value in root project"
  )

lazy val child = project
  .settings(
    testKey := "value in child",
    testKey in ThisBuild := "build-scoped value in child project",
    testKey in Global := "global value in child project"
  )
```

and here's what I see in SBT console:

```
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/private/tmp/sbtt/)
> inspect testKey
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = value in build.sbt
[info] Description:
[info]  A key for test
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/private/tmp/sbtt/}root/*:testKey
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /private/tmp/sbtt/build.sbt:4
[info] Delegates:
[info]  root/*:testKey
[info]  {.}/*:testKey
[info]  */*:testKey
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:testKey
[info]  {.}/*:testKey
[info]  child/*:testKey
> testKey
[info] value in build.sbt
> root/testKey
[info] value in build.sbt
> child/testKey
[info] value in child
> {.}/testKey
[info] global value in child
> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/netvl/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/private/tmp/sbtt/)
> testKey
[info] value in build.sbt
> root/testKey
[info] value in build.sbt
> child/testKey
[info] value in child
> {.}/testKey
[info] build-scoped value in child project
> */testKey
[info] global value in child project
```

So, the conclusion is as follows.

- Values defined at the topmost level in a multi-project SBT build seem to be scoped to the project `build.sbt` belongs to. That is, here `build.sbt` resides in the root directory, and so defining `testKey` in the file directly is the same as defining it in `(project in file(".")).settings(...)` clause. According to SBT output, they also take priority over those defined in `.settings(...)`.
- Keys in larger scopes like `ThisBuild` or `Global` seem to be able to be defined in any project, but "later" projects will then take priority. This is probably related to the order the projects are processed. I have expected that the order of evaluation of `lazy val`s would affect this, and I've tried adding `.aggregate(child)` to the root project to force the child project to be evaluated first, but it didn't seem to have any effect: globally scoped values from child project still have priority.

Therefore, it seems fine to define build-scoped or globally scoped values inside the root project or inside common settings list which is then used in every project. However, assigning different values to a key in build or global scope in different projects will likely lead to a weird behavior - only one of these values will take effect, and which one I don't know.

It would be very nice if all this were explained in the documentation, but at the moment I can't find anything on this behavior there.

I'd gladly accept someone else's answer which would provide more insight on how SBT works in this regard.

Comment: Also, if you are adding to a multi-valued setting such as `concurrentRestrictions` using `+=`, and inadvertently have the same code in every project (because it's in some list of default settings), then you end up with the setting _repeated_ multiple times in the global scope N times, where N is the number of subprojects.