# SBT: Override setting in multi-build dependsOn/aggregate project

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

How do I override a sub-project setting/task in a multi-build SBT project? For example, here are two very simple SBT projects:

*~/projects/backend/build.sbt*

```
name := "backend"

// old version of scala
scalaVersion := "2.9.1"
```

*~/mycode/docker_builder/build.sbt*

```
lazy val backend = RootProject(file("~/projects/backend"))

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
settings(
  // Doesn't work because sub-project already defines name
  name in backend := "sub-overriden",

  // Doesn't override {backend/}backend/*:scalaVersion since backend already defines scalaVersion in Global config
  scalaVersion in backend := "2.10.1",

  // Does define new setting in sub-project: {backend/}backend/test:scalaVersion (because backend did not define scalaVersion in test config)
  scalaVersion in (backend, Test) := "2.10.2"
).
aggregate(sub1)
// dependsOn(sub1)
```

In the sample above, I'm trying to override both *name* and *scalaVersion*, but as noted in the comments, the root project is not able to override any setting/task explicitly defined explicitly in the backend project. Now I'm assuming this is expected behavior, since *RootProject* and it's parent *ProjectReference* point to a completely different SBT build, but if this is the case, why are we allowed to introduce *new* settings into the build, e.g: *scalaVersion in (backend, Test)*?

Any workarounds or other solutions?

*The sample backend project above is a gross oversimplification--our actual backend project in our team is based on the multi-project format with about a dozen or two sub-projects and sbt-plugins--however, fortunately I'm able to reproduce the issue with the listing above.*

Related:
[How to define build-scoped settings in multi-project .sbt builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417180/how-to-define-build-scoped-settings-in-multi-project-sbt-builds)
[Setting javac options for SBT dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350739/setting-javac-options-for-sbt-dependencies)
[Use common settings in SBT `RootProject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460033/use-common-settings-in-sbt-rootproject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very old question, but I could not find any good solution and this question pointed me to a acceptable solution with the following features in sbt:

- You can use ? on a key to return an option
- The effect shown in this question about unset properties in sub-projects can be set in parent
- assigning a key based on another key value

Define the property in both, the child and the parent:

```
lazy val testProperty = settingKey[String]("Test Prop")
```

In the child project you set the property value conditionally like:

```
testProperty := testProperty.?.value.getOrElse("~ child default! ~")
```

In the parent project you set the property value normally:

```
childProject / testProperty := "# parent override! "
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any way to override settings from the subproject directly from the main build. When you create the `Project` its `settings` doesn't even contain the definitions from the subproject's `build.sbt` yet.

What you can do though is call `.addSbtFiles(file("overrides.sbt"))` (paths are resolved relative to the subproject's base dir) and then put the overrides into this separate file which is loaded after the subproject's `build.sbt`.

Comment: Could you give an example of something that would appear in this overrides file?