# How to change the order in which settings are applied to an sbt subproject?

Tags: scala, sbt

Given a simple project structure like this:

```
+ lib1/
|   + build.sbt
+ build.sbt
```

where

`./lib1/build.sbt` is:

```
name := "Library 1"
```

`./build.sbt` is:

```
lazy val lib1 = 
  project.in(file("lib1")).settings(name := "Blah blah", version := "1.2.3")
```

What seems to happen is that settings in `./lib1/build.sbt` override settings for the same project specified in `build.sbt` because `lib1/name` resolves to "Library 1" and not "Blah blah" but `lib1/version` resolves to "1.2.3" from the sbt console.

Is there any way I could make it the other way around, so that I can override some settings specified in `./lib1/build.sbt` in `./build.sbt` instead?

**Edit**:

Similarly, if `./lib1/build.sbt` is just a plain list of settings as above I can do this in the main `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val lib1 = project.in(file("lib1"))
lazy val lib2 = project.in(file("lib2")).dependsOn(lib1)
```

and I can see that it works by checking `show lib2/internalDependencyClasspath` in console, however if `./lib1/build.sbt` is instead

```
lazy val lib1 = project.in(file(".")).settings(name := "Library 1")
```

I can no longer use `dependsOn` in the main `build.sbt`

**Related**:

[SBT: Override setting in multi-build dependsOn/aggregate project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955217/sbt-override-setting-in-multi-build-dependson-aggregate-project)

Comment: I think it's not possible to change this order. I won't give you any proofs, but I think it's considered bad practice nowadays to use multiple `build.sbt`s in subprojects. You can define all your subprojects, their settings and inter-dependencies in the root `build.sbt`.

Comment: But what if I want the subproject to be a standalone buildable/publishable library?

Comment: Then just make it an independent sbt project, why do you want to _redefine_ it in a multi-project build? You can probably still create a "meta-project" which will aggregate several such independent libraries via source dependencies.

Comment: For instance the library has a jar dependency on another library (for the standalone build) that I want to replace with a source dependency for the multi-project build.

Comment: I see now. Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve it.